# Invalid argument with SendMsg() cmsg in golang

Tags: go, sockets, timestamp

I am new in golang and socket programming. I am trying to send msg with cmsg , but the error keep showing with "Invalid argument" when invoking `syscall.Sendmsg()`. I am sure that call works well without `cmsgBytes`.

```
...
    cmsg := syscall.Cmsghdr{}
    cmsg.Level = syscall.SOL_SOCKET
    cmsg.Type = syscall.SO_TIMESTAMPING
    cmsg.Len = uint64(syscall.CmsgLen(0))
    cmsgBytes := (*[unsafe.Sizeof(cmsg)]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&cmsg))[:]

    if err := syscall.Sendmsg(fd, pkt, cmsgBytes, dstAddr, 0); err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, err
}
```

Please tell me some example of sending cmsg data with `SO_TIMESTAMPING` or anything can help.